# Copy and paste array formulas using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some formulas in a row.  I want to copy them down to the end of the rest of my data.

When using normal formulas, the following code works:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set formRange = Range(.Range("G2"), .Range("O2").End(xlToRight))
    formRange.Copy
    formRange.Resize(Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

However, when I replace some formulas with array formulas, I get a Run-time error 1004 that says `PasteSpecial method of Range class failed`.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What your code does is copy and paste in the same `Range`. So if the result of `formRange.Resize(...)` is greater than 1 row (since you are resizing just that and not offsetting or anything) it will throw subscript due to *Excels Rule* that you cannot change part of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you cannot change part of an array. So try this:

```
Dim formRange As Range, arrForm As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set formRange = Range(.Range("G2"), _
        .Range("O2").End(xlToRight))
    arrForm = formRange.FormulaArray
    formRange.ClearContents
    formRange.Resize(.Range("D" & _
        .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).FormulaArray = arrForm
End With
```

Btw, take note of the extra dots I put in this line:

```
formRange.Resize(.Range("D" & _
    .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).FormulaArray = arrForm
```

I assumed that you are pertaining to *D Column* of the same sheet.
Above works if it is just one array formula output in several ranges.
If each cell has different array formula, then just add offset in your code like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set formRange = Range(.Range("G2"), _
        .Range("O2").End(xlToRight))
    formRange.Copy
    formRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Range("D" & _
        .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Range.FormulaArray method:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set formRange = Range(.Range("G2"), .Range("O2").End(xlToRight))
    formRange.Copy
    Set newRange = (Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    newRange.FormulaArray = formRange
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

Comment: I follow the logic but I can't quite get it to work.  The `newRange` gives me object required errors.

Comment: You need to define newRange, please put Dim newRange As Range at the top of your code.

Comment: Hmm, I defined it but it's still erroring.  I'll try to figure it out after lunch!

Comment: Yeah, I got the syntax to work, but it's just pasting values.  Not sure what's up

Comment: Can you try putting an equals sign in front of `formRarange`: `newRange.FormulaArray = "=" & formRange`. What did you change in the syntax to make it correct?